# Polymer 2.0 custom element with Function property

Tags: polymer-2.x

I am trying to create a polymer 2.0 custom element with function property. But not able to find an example to refer to. The Polymer 2.0 documentation mentions "Function" as a supported property but there is no syntax/example available.
Can somebody point me to a example where a callback function is passed as a property?
Need to pass a call back function to an element.For example

```html
<custom-element size = "20" response = "callback"></custom-element>
class CustomElement extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'custom-element'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          prop1: {
            type: String,
            value: 'firebasetest-element'
          },
              callback:
          {
               type: Function,
               notify: true
          }
}
```

Comment: can you be more clear? As i can assume that you are talking about properties static method? is it? and **why don't you consider [observers](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/observers) to the properties?**

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are talking about, but you can use data binding using methods like this:

```
<my-element some-attribute="[[myMethod(observerProperty.subProperty)]]"></my-element>
```

and in your method declaration:

```
myMethod() {
  var something = "can be anything"
  return something
}
```

With this, your "someAttribute" property of my-element will be a string "can be anything", and myMethod gets called anytime "observerProperty.subProperty" gets changed.

Comment: Update the query. Need to associate a callback in custom element.